# How to insert in textarea sorted data from variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

HTML:

```
<button id="myButton">Button</button>
<br />
<textarea id="imgLinks" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myButton").click(function() {
        var finalLink = '["img/1.jpg","img/sg.png","img/dfsg.jpg","img/484dg.jpg"]'
        $('#imgLinks').focus();
        $('#imgLinks').val($('#imgLinks').val() + finalLink);
    });
});
```

How to insert data from **finalLink** in **textarea** like as:

```
https://example.com/1.jpg
https://example.com/sg.png
https://example.com/dfsg.jpg
https://example.com/484dg.jpg
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Qartvela/qxo73mfa/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map to modify the link elements according to your need and join them with `\n` before setting them as the *textarea* value:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myButton").click(function(){
    var finalLink = '["img/1.jpg","img/sg.png","img/dfsg.jpg","img/484dg.jpg"]'
    $('#imgLinks').focus();
    finalLink = JSON.parse(finalLink).map(l => 'https://example.com/'+l).join('\n');
    $('#imgLinks').val(finalLink);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myButton">Button</button>
<br />
<textarea id="imgLinks" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
```

Comment: How to add **\n** for last link/url?

Comment: On android still: `["img/1.jpg","img/sg.png","img/dfsg.jpg","img/484dg.jpg"]`

Comment: @ErekleM., i guess the issue code be some where else in your development environment.

Comment: **@Mamun**, Thanks for the advice. I deleted all the code (with many functions) for upload images and wrote a new code :) Now everything is in order.